Getting unpermitted parameter: :locale in react on rails
I getting the below error.
    error
'  ↳ app/controllers/concerns/set_locale.rb:35:in `switch_locale'
Unpermitted parameter: :locale'

Here is my set_locale.rb
module SetLocale
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    around_action :switch_locale
    helper_method :current_locale
    helper_method :switch_locale_urls
  end

  def current_locale
    extract_locale.presence || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def switch_locale_urls
    locale_regex = %r{^/(#{I18n.available_locales.join('|')})/}i

    I18n.available_locales.index_with do |locale|
      if request.method == 'GET' && original_fullpath.match(locale_regex)
        original_fullpath.gsub(locale_regex, "/#{locale}/")
      else
        root_path(locale: locale)
      end
    end.to_h
  end

  protected def original_fullpath
    request.original_fullpath
  end

  private def switch_locale(&action)
    locale = extract_locale || I18n.default_locale
    response.set_header('Content-Language', locale.to_s)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("alter session set nls_sort = 'THAI_M'") #this is line 35 where its causing error
    I18n.with_locale(locale, &action)
  end

  private def extract_locale
    parsed_locale = params[:locale]
    I18n.available_locales.map(&:to_s).include?(parsed_locale) ? parsed_locale : nil
  end

  private def default_url_options
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end
end

And below is my ApplicationController.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include BasicAuthProtection
  include CurrentUserSession
  include ErrorPages
  include SetLocale
  include Pagination

  helper VimeoHelper
  helper SVGHelper
  helper ChunksHelper

  protect_from_forgery
  per_request_react_rails_prerenderer

  before_action :permit_additional_params
  before_action :add_ssr_variables, :store_location

  
  def store_location
    unless request.path.include?('session')
      session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath
    end
  end
  
  # Permit the locale parameter globally
  protected def permit_locale_param
    params.permit(:locale)
  end
  
  # rubocop:disable Rails/OutputSafety
  protected def add_ssr_variables
    react_rails_prerenderer
    .context
      .exec("global.I18N_LOCALE = #{I18n.locale.to_json.html_safe}")
      react_rails_prerenderer
      .context
      .exec("global.FORM_AUTHENTICITY_TOKEN = #{form_authenticity_token.to_json.html_safe}")
    end
    # rubocop:enable all
    private
  
    def permit_additional_params
      # Permit the locale and other custom params
      params.permit(:locale, :page, :per_page, :sort, filters: { cuisine: [], dish_type: [], main_ingredient: [] })
    end
  end

I have tried adding params.permit but still its not working. Recently there was a change of db but .env I have properly add all the fields. Since the DB is changed am facing this issue. Below is the version of used packages

Rails: v6.0.3.6, Ruby: v2.7.2, Bundler: 2.1.4

Please do help if anyone knows the work around

params[:locale] is an unpermitted parameter, so using it will trigger this error.
Instead of accessing it directly from params, create a method that returns just the permitted params needed in this file like so:
private dev locale_params
  params.permit(:locale)
end

Then change your lookup code to refer to that instead:
private def extract_locale
  parsed_locale = locale_params[:locale]
  I18n.available_locales.map(&:to_s).include?(parsed_locale) ? parsed_locale : nil
end

